# R - creating generics out of base functions

Tags: r, generics

I would like to use the nrow function to mean something slightly different for a class I will define. But I also don't want to mask the nrow function, so I would like to redefine nrow as

```
nrow <- function(x) UseMethod("nrow")

nrow.matrix <- function(x) base::nrow(x)
nrow.data.frame <- function(x) base::nrow(x)
nrow.list <- function(x) base::nrow(x) # should return NULL
nrow.numeric <- function(x) base::nrow(x) # should return NULL
nrow.character <- function(x) base::nrow(x) # should return NULL
nrow.ts <- function(x) base::nrow(x) # should return NULL
```

Is this kind of stuff, kosher? Is this the wrong way to do it?

Comment: not tried but maybe if you gave a "dim" attribute to your class the function `nrow` will work and return `dim(x)[1]`?

Comment: `nrow` is not a .Primitive.

Comment: You're, right will edit.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just define a default method:

```
x <- 1
class(x) <- "myclass"

nrow <-  function(x) UseMethod("nrow")
nrow.default <- base::nrow
nrow.myclass <- function(x) 42

nrow(x)
#[1] 42

nrow(matrix(1:15, ncol=3))
#[1] 5
```

Comment: Yes this is correct, just found it as well, small modification would be to define nrow.default before UseMethod is used so that one could, nrow.default <- nrow, but it isn't too important. Also, for nrow it might not be too important, but it might be better to use, nrow <-  function(...) UseMethod("nrow"), that is use "...".

Comment: Why is the two step:

loadings <- function(x, ...) UseMethod("loadings")
loadings.default <- function(x, ...) stats::loadings(x) 

Suggested over the one-step:

    setGeneric("loadings")